# Configure global CSS in Deno Fresh

Tags: typescript, deno, freshjs

I'm trying to link a stylesheet that will style the `html` and `body` elements in my app. At the moment I've tried using the `<Head />` component but this is only sent with the component it's imported inside, so other routes don't get the stylesheet.

```js
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
        <Head>
            <link rel='stylesheet' href="main.css" />
        </Head>
        ...
    </>
  )
}
```

Can I import this globally? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

1. Create an `_app.tsx` file in `/routes`([this wraps the entire app](https://fresh.deno.dev/docs/concepts/app-wrapper)), and add the `<Head />` component within this:

```js
import { AppProps } from "$fresh/server.ts"
import { Head } from "$fresh/runtime.ts"

export default function App({ Component }: AppProps) {
    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
            </Head>
            <Component />
        </>
    )
}
```

2. Add `main.css` in `/static`

Then the stylesheet goes to all routes.